# sum of list without change length of list pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to groupby column and sum of list for another column in dataframe, but it seems like the following code is not working. The length of each user is different after I use `sum` function.
`dt2 = dt.groupby(['user']).sum()`

the data like this:

```html
user vector
1    [1,2,3,4,5]
2    [1,3,2,4,5]
1    [3,3,3,4,4]
1    [1,2,2,1,1]
2    [1,1,2,0,0]
```

The expect table should be

```html
user vector
1    [5,7,8,9,9]
2    [2,4,4,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way which creates a df based on the `vector` column and groups on `user` and sum , finally `aggregate` as list on `axis=1`:

```
(pd.DataFrame(df['vector'].tolist())
  .groupby(df['user']).sum().agg(list,axis=1).reset_index(name='vector'))
```

---

```
   user            vector
0     1  [5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
1     2   [2, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```